# How to program to remove a USER LABEL after replying the email?

Tags: gmail-api

I created a USER LABEL 'TO DO'in my INBOX. Once I have replied to this email, I want google to automatically remove my 'TO DO' label. How do I write a script (and what script) to remove this USER Label?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet: I don't know where to start